# Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(…): 'NativeReanimated' could not be found

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

In my React Native App I install React Navigation, install React Navigation Stack and finally install Drawer Navigation.
If I use the stack everything works perfectly, but when I try to use Drawer Navigation I get this error that I have not been able to solve.
I have cleared cache, uninstalled "NativeReanimated", reinstalled,
testing on a physical device ... And nothing, I can't find the solution.

I have followed all the steps in the react navigation documentation and nothing. (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started and https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation)

Node version: 14.15.4.

Working on Windows and using Android.

My package.json:

```
  "name": "themovieapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.18.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"[enter image description here][1]
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

When I run "react-native info":

```
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.18363
    CPU: (12) x64 AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor
    Memory: 4.60 GB / 15.93 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.15.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.22.5 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
    npm: 7.6.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 28, 29, 30
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 30.0.2
      System Images: android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
    Windows SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
    Visual Studio: Not Found
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_275 - C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\openjdk-8u275-b01\bin\javac.EXE
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
    react-native: 0.64.0 => 0.64.0
    react-native-windows: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcRCi.png

Comment: As a temporally solution, I have installed react-native-reanimated version 1.13.2 and it seems to work... The react-native-reanimated GitHub page is filled with the same error so it seems to be an error of its own library.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation/#babel-plugin

1. `yarn add react-native-reanimated@next`
2. Add Reanimated's babel plugin to your babel.config.js:`'react-native-reanimated/plugin'`
3. Turn on Hermes engine by editing android/app/build.gradle:
4. Plug Reanimated in MainApplication.java

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/

1. Updating MainActivity.java
2. first import in your index.js file: `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';`

**Finish... Clear cash**

1. yarn start --reset-cache